# Access 2016 Records between two dates query

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, between

Currently trying to grab records from a table between two dates, in this case between 4/1/2021 and 3/31/2022. I'm pulling from a linked table to the database and yet cannot get any records from either query I've pulled.

I've used the following queries:

```
SELECT [Req Update].[ASSET #], [Req Update].[ADHOC DATE]
FROM [Req Update]
WHERE ((([Req Update].[ASSET #]) Is Not Null) 
 AND (([Req Update].[ADHOC DATE])>=[Start Date] 
 And ([Req Update].[ADHOC DATE])<=[End Date]));
```

This one above I have set up to enter in the start and end date since next year it will have to change. I'd prefer to have it like this going forwards.

This query below though has the dates I need without manually entering the start and end dates.

```
SELECT [Req Update].[ASSET #], [Req Update].[ADHOC DATE]
FROM [Req Update]
WHERE ((([Req Update].[ASSET #]) Is Not Null) 
AND (([Req Update].[ADHOC DATE])>='4/1/2021' 
And ([Req Update].[ADHOC DATE])<='3/31/2022'));
```

The Req Update linked table has 5 records that should show up, all are within the dates I add/need.

Specifically I'm thinking either I'm missing something or maybe the data isn't matching up correctly. Any assistance with this would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is the data type of your "date" columns?  Why are you not using date literals for the comparison?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff    The data type of my column is Date and I apologize I'm unsure of what you mean about date literals. I've seen a couple videos where they add # before and after the dates but for my queries when I try for example #4/1/2021# it changes into '#4/1/2021#'. Is that what you mean?

Comment: _ it changes into '#4/1/2021#'_ ... if so, the field is _text_, not DateTime. Are you linking the table from SQL Server? If so, change the datatype from _DateTime2_ to _DateTime_.

Comment: The table is linked to a excel file with Date as the format type for that specific field.

Comment: Excel does NOT really have data types. Even a column formatted for date display will allow alpha entries. Access should determine 'data type' by examination of first 10 or so rows of Excel. However, this process is far from perfect.

Comment: I just tested linking a simple worksheet and Access does recognize the date column as a date/time type, even without defining column as "Date".

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft Access dates are not in quotes, they are between pound-signs (#).  Change this:

```
AND (([Req Update].[ADHOC DATE])>='4/1/2021' 
And ([Req Update].[ADHOC DATE])<='3/31/2022'
```

to this:

```
AND (([Req Update].[ADHOC DATE])>=#4/1/2021#
And ([Req Update].[ADHOC DATE])<=#3/31/2022#
```

Better yet, change it to

```
AND [Req Update].[ADHOC DATE]) between #4/1/2021# and #3/31/2022#
```